# Flutter Provider Package doesn't update

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Aim: I am trying to build the Pomodoro application and after the timer completed I want to update the time spent on the task total time spend. Even though I am using the flutter Provider package, It doesn't work.

[Task Data][1],[Button in statefulwidget][2],[MainDart File][3],[app task list interface, 0 Min needs to update][4],[Stateful widget interface with button needs to update task data][5]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUh6j.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSpxW.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wWLL.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tkkH.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1xIl.png

Comment: Could you please upload some source code of this implementation? It's a bit hard to help you if there's nothing to reference

Comment: I updated the pictures

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? With screenshots it is not readable.

Comment: Looking at your project I think you should build something a little simpler.

Comment: If you need ideas take a look at a fork of mine, with a collection of dozens of project ideas from beginners to experts to get you started

Comment: https://github.com/TheArchitect123/app-ideas

Comment: Please don't do tutorial videos, because they don't teach you anything. Go through the flutter documentation and build projects from scratch, by yourself, and refer to stack overflow when you need it

Comment: Do enough of these, and you can put flutter on your skill belt

Comment: Okay, I will do that. thank you :))